# Generate a random bool with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

How to efficiently generate a random bool with Tensorflow? Doesen't need to be cryptographically safe. Ideally only using  `tensorflow as tf`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
tf.random.uniform([]) < p  # p=0.5 for 50% chance
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow (2.9.1) documentation seems to give this:

Code:

```
# samples has shape [1, 5], where each value is either 0 or 1 with equal
# probability.
samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5, 0.5]]), 5)
print(samples) # I added this line
```

Result:

```
tf.Tensor([[0 1 0 1 1]], shape=(1, 5), dtype=int64)
```

For your application, I think the call might need to be:

```
samples = tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5, 0.5]]), 1)
```

which gives:

```
tf.Tensor([[1]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=int64)
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/categorical